# Liferay: timeout on the regeneration of the search indexes

Tags: search, indexing, liferay, liferay-6, rebuild

When launching the functionality of a "Rebuild all search indexes." very often the request times out, perhaps because the browser waits too long the answer.
How do I fix this? As it is I can not figure out when it ends the regeneration of the indices and if unsuccessful

Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data set is pretty big regenerating the indexes can take a lot of time. There’s no ‘fix’ for this. You could, for example, use a different Indexer, such as Solr, to remove the burden from the machine running Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

I can always tell when it is done by running it late at night during low traffic hours and monitoring the JMX (CPU) activity and (tomcat) logs. Both will give indications when the indexing is completed with various tasks and starting new ones, but I find the JMX monitoring to be clearest. In our case, there is around 500+MB of index data on each node and it takes ~ 2.5 hours give or take. I also kick off indexing on each application node, since we have found the "cluster link" software unreliable to copy the index across cluster nodes...